# Write a program that reads a word and prints all substrings, sorted by length

Tags: python

Just like the question asks... I'm new to Python.

We are NOT allowed to use slice function.

```
input = input("Please enter word here: ")
length = len(input)
x = 0
y = 0

for x in input:
    print(x)
    for y in input:
        print(x+y)
```

I know it doesnt work. It's my best effort. Could someone please help me? Keeping it relatively simple like the code I already have? Thank you so much.

For example, if the user provides the input "tom", the program prints

```
"t"
"o"
"m"
"to"
"om"
"tom"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you give a proper sample of what your expected input and output is. If I enter the word `racecar`. What should the output be.

Comment: I edited in an example to my question.

Comment: Why there is no `tm` ?

Comment: @GLHF I guess the assignment is to search for continuous substrings.

Comment: `tm` isn't really a substring.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you are looking for (with no slicing OR indexing):

```
input = 'abcdef'
length = len(input)

for i in range(length):
    s = [input[c] for c in range(i,length)]
    output = ''
    for j in range(length-i):
        output += s.pop(0)
        print output
```

Output:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
b
bc
bcd
bcde
bcdef
c
cd
cde
cdef
d
de
def
e
ef
f
```

A quicker, more elegant/pythonic and more efficient way of achieving the same result is with a quick list comprehension:

```
substrings = [input[i:j+1] for i in xrange(length) for j in xrange(i,length)]
for s in substrings: print s
```

Comment: He means no such thing as `input[i:j+1]`, for example.  See the docs on [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice).

Comment: Just edited now. I understand what not using slicing IS but my whole point is: why would anyone use a collection type which you can't index/slice? Or an iterable which you can't iterate over? It doesn't make any sense. Just makes the code more verbose and inefficient (`pop(0)` time complexity is O(n), which is pretty bad).

Comment: It certainly doesn't make sense; I agree with you there.

Comment: It's for an assignment

Comment: There's the answer for your assignment without using any external module or slicing. Looks more like a C assignment than a Python one though.

Comment: You're gonna kill me... ha.

We have also not yet learned s.pop or for statements being assigned to variables. Could you find a way to take those out? You're really being a big help, thank you so much.

Comment: You can substitute it with `s[j]` if indexing is allowed.

Comment: By the way, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations

user = input ("Please enter word here: ")

d = []
y = 1

while y != len(user)+1:
    for x in combinations(user,y):
        d.append(x)
    y += 1

print (d)
```

You can use **combinations** module for this.

Output;

```
Please enter word here: tom
[('t',), ('o',), ('m',), ('t', 'o'), ('t', 'm'), ('o', 'm'), ('t', 'o', 'm')]
>>>
```

Comment: Could you do this without 'combinations', 'append', 'break', and 'while True:'?

Comment: Could you do this without all of Python? lmao.

Comment: I think the `('t', 'm')` is not wanted.

Comment: @pp_ Well at first I thought that but after then I just realized OP forget to wrote. Probably. I don't know, since he wants a solution without any Python thing. :)

Comment: @ChristianLomboy I changed `while True`, but sorry can't remove other things. Don't know a possible solution with your request.

Comment: @GLHF First semester as a comp sci major, only my second month of coding. Cut me some slack! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I will just give you a hint :
One variable "first_lettre_of_substring"
One variable "length_of_substring"
And without any slicing (basically using a few for loops instead), you can come up with every possibilities.

Good luck

Comment: I feel like you're onto something. Working now to see what I can do.